# How to extract values from a multidimensional array to form another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array with 4 values: item, category, checked, number:

```
var MyArray = [
["coke", "beverages", "checked", 000],
["baguette", "bread", "checked", 001],
["water", "beverages", "checked", 000],
["pepsi", "beverages", "checked", 000],
["wholemeal", "bread", "checked", 001],
...
]
```

How do I make more arrays to categorise them like this:

```
var beverages = ["coke", "pepsi", "water"]; // more drinks from above array...
var bread = ["baguette", "wholemeal"]; // more types of bread from above array...
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `var beverages = MyArray[0]` ?

Comment: You cannot create dynamic variable names, only dynamic keys of an object. You could e.g. create the following structure: `var object = { beverages: [...], bread: [...] };`

Comment: What comes after `"coke",..`. It's not obvious from the data

Comment: Are the items you want to group by always in the second position? Please show more data, perhaps with different beverages...

Comment: sorry more beverages come after coke

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Where are the other beverages? Do you have more items like `["pepsi", "beverages", "checked", 000]` in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the items like this. Create an accumulator object with each type of food as key. [`Destructure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each inner array to get the first and second item.

```js
var MyArray = [
  ["coke", "beverages", "checked", 000],
  ["baguette", "bread", "checked", 001],
  ["water", "beverages", "checked", 000],
  ["pepsi", "beverages", "checked", 000],
  ["wholemeal", "bread", "checked", 001],
]

const grouped = MyArray.reduce((r, [item, type]) => {
  r[type] = r[type] || [];
  r[type].push(item)
  return r;
}, {})

const { bread, beverages } = grouped

console.log(bread, beverages)
```

This is how the `grouped` object will look. You can use destrucutring to get more categories of food

```
{
  "beverages": [ "coke", "water", "pepsi" ],
  "bread": [ "baguette", "wholemeal" ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Which part of this code takes the bread and beverages' items? The const? Just asking in case in the future I want to add more categories.

Comment: @AshleyHoward I have updated the answer. From `reduce`, you get an object with each unique category as it's key. If you have more types, you can add the key names to the destructuring  `const { bread, beverages, dessert } = grouped`

Answer (score -2):

It could be like this :

```
var beverages = MyArray.map(data =>  data[0])
var bread = MyArray.map(data =>  data[1]);
```

and so on.